# Alternative to replace "Math.random" in Google Ads (Flash AS2)?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I am working on a banner that will go on Google ad network. However, Google does not accept ads that use math.random in the code.

I found few codes, but it does not work. The most relevant I found is this, but still not working on me
http://wondergiant.com/2013/03/random-without-math-random/

Could anyone help me on this how does it work on AS2?

Here is the original quote:

```
    var pressed = false;

    var go = function() {

    width = 300;
    height = 200;
    max_snowsize = 20;
    snowflakes = 15;


for (i=0; i<snowflakes; i++) {

    t = attachMovie("snow", "snow"+i, i);
    t._alpha = 40+Math.random()*60;
    t._x = -(width/2)+Math.random()*(1.5*width);
    t._y = -(height/2)+Math.random()*(1.5*height);
    t._xscale = t._yscale=50+Math.random()*(max_snowsize*10);
    t.k = 1+Math.random()*2;
    t.wind = -1.5+Math.random()*(1.4*3);
    t.onEnterFrame = mover;
}
    };


    mover = function() {
this._y += this.k;
this._x += this.wind;
if (this._y>height+10) {
    this._y = -20;
}
if (this._x>width+20) {
    this._x = -(width/2)+Math.random()*(1.5*width);
    this._y = -20;
} else if (this._x<-20) {
    this._x = -(width/2)+Math.random()*(1.5*width);
    this._y = -20;
}

if(pressed){
    this._alpha -= 1;
}
    }

    // start snow

    go();
```

Comment: Doesn't `Google` accept `math.random` in the code?

Comment: Unfortunately Google does not accept this code.They didn't indicate the reason as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a way to get Current Time in that banner, use that time value as seed to run your custom algorithm. Ull be able to generate random only if you get random seed, might be even any information you could get, page views, users online, system processor usage, (all these accesses are restricted i believe. There is reason for banners to use as2 not as3) but u might find some hole maybe :)

1. [sys](http://docs.brajeshwar.com/as2/System.html)

ouh there was a way to capture user scroll wheel usage - a good seed i believe, or at least mouse hover event could be a seed for shore.